# MediaRecorder crashes while trying to record audio from Bluetooth headset

Tags: android-bluetooth, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, headset

i am trying to call

> mediaRecorder.start()

. It gives this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1143)
    at com.yyy.mystory.xxx.ui.camera.CameraVideoFragment$startRecordingVideo$2$onConfigured$1.run(CameraVideoFragment.kt:691)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

When i record from phone then it works perfectly fine but when i try to record viabluetooth haedset then it gives crash as above. My code is somewhat as below:

```
 if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder?.release()
        mediaRecorder = null
    }
    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()

    mediaRecorder?.apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        setOutputFile(nextVideoAbsolutePath)
        setVideoEncodingBitRate(compositionQuality.videoBitrate)
        setAudioEncodingBitRate(compositionQuality.audioBitrate)
        setAudioChannels(2)
        setAudioSamplingRate(44100)
        setVideoFrameRate(60)            

        setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        prepare()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys after looking for the solution everywhere, i found that MediaPlayer was not for playing. It was due to the media button event getting called twice for Volume_up and volume_down button from bluetooth device. Just start mediaRecorder only on particular event either for KeyEvent.ACTION_UP or for KeyEvent.ACTION_UP. This resolves my problem.

```
 mMediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, TAG)
    mMediaSession?.setCallback(object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        override fun onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent: Intent): Boolean {
            // Consume the media button event here. Should not send it to other apps.
            val event = mediaButtonIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) as KeyEvent
            var action = event.action

            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //call mediaplayer.start() from here
            }
            return true
        }
    })
```